# Определение рода существительного

Tags: грамматика, существительные, род

Почему род существительного в русском языке определяется по окончанию слова в именительном падеже, а не в родительном (как, например, в латинском)?

Answer (score 1):

С чего вы взяли, что род в русском определяется по окончанию им. п.?

Кофе — среднего/мужского рода, хотя окончания, строго говоря, у него нет (выделение нулевого мне не представляется логичным (примечание для специалистов)).

Панк — мужского рода, окончание нулевое;
боль — женского, а окончание тоже нулевое.

С таким подходом, какой вы описали, никакой системы не получается.

Род слова определяется либо набором всех окончаний (парадигмой), либо вообще только в контекстах, где, допустим, перед существительным стоит согласующееся с ним слово, ср.: *Какое вкусное кофе я сегодня испробовал!*

Comment: Так же род определён семантикой. К примеру, если иностранец, зная дословный перевод и окончания родов, произносит слово по-русски, а в его языке оно другого рода, он произносит зачастую то окончание, которое соответствует роду его языка.

Comment: @Aer а зачем тогда падеж родительным называется, если по нёму род существительного не определить?

Comment: @prostorech родительный — калька с лат. genitīvus. Вообще, полагалось, что он отражает отношения родства: _дочь (кого?) Мар**ии**_.